# high net IO time in weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHttp

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic

i am using jersey as rest client running in weblogic server, and looks like the http client is taking much time on net IO. the call stack is below

```
java.io.BuffererdInputStream.read
  weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHttp
     weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.pasreHeader
       weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP
           com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get
```

performance profile shows java.io.BuffererdInputStream.read took 60% of total request time in waiting net IO. it can also be seen in a small load of 2 concurrent http client.

what is possible reason that cause a net IO problem?

my environment
weblogic server 10.3
os: linux

Comment: And what is your expectation? The general expectation is that, yes, I/O is the performance bottleneck.

Comment: thank you for the input. is it saying the client spending 60% on net IO is normal? I am to see if there require adjustment on client side or tuning on weblogic to make it better.  could you comments more？

Answer (score 0):

Spending most of your application threads' time in network I/O is normal when using a blocking web framework.  Moving bits over a network is orders of magnitude slower than, say, moving bits in and out of memory in a single computer.

Low level networking protocols are designed to guarantee a message gets where it's going without being changed en route, *not* to do that particularly fast.

Comment: thanks a lot for response. in my understanding of your comments, the net io issue can be workarounded by adopting a new non-blocking web framework instead of jersey?  do you have comments what I can do to overcome this problem?